# Managing Management

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

[file-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-management) has **438 questions**
[power-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-management) has 326 questions
[password-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-management) has 106 questions 
[memory-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) has 51 questions
[project-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/project-management) has 45 questions
[time-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-management) has 20 questions
[document-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/document-management) has 18 questions
[knowledge-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-management) has 14 questions
[task-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-management) has 5 questions

we also have 111 questions for [management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/management) and I'm not even sure what they are managing.

<s>##Suggestions:

1. [task-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-management) is a synonym for [productivity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/productivity) (124 questions);

2. [knowledge-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-management), [document-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/document-management), [password-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/password-management), [file-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-management) all be synonyms for new [information-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/information-management);

3. [power-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-management) and [memory-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) become synonyms for new [hardware-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-management);

4. [management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/management) be broken down into different categories and dispersed as needed with [management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/management) a synonym for new [information-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/information-management)

5. [time-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-management) be a synonym for [project-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/project-management)

6. [asset](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asset) (3 questions) also be a synonym for [hardware-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-management)</s>

**7. Clippy does all this work.**

Please discuss, I'm sure I'm not spot on with all of this.

---

### Edit

1. What is document management? It has no wiki
2. File Management is left alone.
3. Time-Management and Task-Management and [organizing] synonym for Productivity
4. Power-Management and Memory Management into Hardware-Management
5. Knowledge-Management, Password-Management, [document management?] into [information-management]
6. [Management] disambiguated and becomes part of [information-management]
7. [note-taking] synonym for [notes] while taking all [lotus/notes] out of [notes] and into [lotus-note]

Comment: Disagree with 2. Password management is very specific, document management as well.

Comment: Time management also has not much to do with project management, thinking about it.

Comment: @slhck Is document management akin to version control? Because we have that tag too.

Comment: No, that's something different :)

Comment: I really think we should just split up `[management]` into one of the more specific ones we have, that's all.

Comment: We also have [note-taking] (9) and [organizing] (32) in the mix here.

Comment: Hm. `organizing` seems worth disambiguating. Note taking is a very special task again, but it can be merged into `[notes]` (if we move the incorrectly tagged Lotus Notes ones into `[lotus-notes]`).

Comment: My other thought was `[time management]` be synonymized into `[productivity]`

Comment: That should work I guess.

Comment: I still don't understand what document and password management are if they aren't part of information management. I guess I'm having trouble with that. File Management is clear it doesn't belong though.

Comment: They *are* part of information management, but **our tag system is not a taxonomy**. It's not hierarchical, and unless users automatically think about "information management" when they actually mean "password management", this is not going to work out. Real-world analogy: If we have clearly defined "apples" and "oranges", why merge them into "fruits" if people ask "apple" questions and tag them with "apple"?

Comment: @slhck roger on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To formalize this one, I suggest:

- Retag [management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/management) into one of the more specific ones we already have
- Retag [note-taking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/note-taking) into [notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/notes) (and watch out for Lotus Notes questions that should actually go to [lotus-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes)).
- Retag [organizing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/organizing) using one of the more specific tags above.
- Get rid of [asset](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/asset) with anything that's better suited (no idea though)
- Possibly merge [time-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/time-management) into [productivity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/productivity)

Comment: Any particular reason you're going to `notes` instead of `note-taking`? IMO the latter is easier to understand (sounds less like a product name).

Comment: Simply because it's used more often (even subtracting the number of Lotus Notes questions).